# How to query increased sales every day a month in SQL Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Can some 1 help me with SQL redshift query to get the result the way mentioned below

My table:

```
SalesDate  | Amount($)

2022-03-01 | 4     
2022-03-01 | 5     
2022-03-02 | 3     
2022-03-02 | 10     
2022-03-02 | 12      
2022-03-03 | 1    
 etc..
```

**I want to have an increased sales table group by `SalesDate`  :**

```
SalesDate  | Amount($)

2022-03-01 | 9    
2022-03-02 | 34   
 etc...
```

Currently, I tried to use this query but doesn't work:

```
select distinct salesdate::date as date_number
, sum(*) over (order by salesdate::date) asc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as amount
from mytable
where salesdate >= '2022-03-01'
```

So I received the result not as my wanted. It increase but not as my wanted:

```
SalesDate  | Amount($)

2022-03-01 | 4

2022-03-01 | 9  

2022-03-02 | 12

2022-03-02 | 22

2022-03-02 | 34
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `group by` with aggregate function in a subquery, before use window function.

```
SELECT date_number,
       sum(amount) over (order by date_number) totalAmount
FROM (
    select salesdate::date as date_number, 
           sum(Amount) as amount
    from mytable
    where salesdate >= '2022-03-01'
    GROUP BY salesdate::date
) t1
```

Comment: Good answer and splitting into 2 selects can add clarity.  For simplicity it should be noted that window functions run AFTER aggregates so this can be done in one layer of select.